# How to enlarge the wordpress post image?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm having trouble figuring out how to enlarge the wordpress post image size . I tried changing the default media settings and also attempted to use numerous resizing plugin such as Regenerate Thumbnail or Force Regenerate Thumbnail but it hasn't done the trick .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7KSi.png

Answer (score 0):

have you included **add_image_size('enlargedimg', width, height, true)** in your functions.php?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

once you add this, then try and regenerate the thumbnails using the regenerate thumbnail plugin.

Then in the theme file you'd like to change the size on the frontend for call in **get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'enlargedimg')** or **the_post_thumbnail('enlargedimg')**

Comment: Hi dgas02 , thanks for the help . For the last part , Where do I change the theme file ? I don't know where to add this specific code " get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'enlargedimg') or the_post_thumbnail('enlargedimg') "

Comment: What is this a post, page or custom post type you are trying to change? is this a custom theme or one of the default themes?

Comment: Hi , It is a custom theme . It's a post I want to change

Comment: you will have to edit/create an index.php or single.php file. Single.php will allow you to edit the individual post's page whereas index will be the page that displays all of your posts

Comment: It's all the pictures in the post I want to change